# Distinguish array from single value in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two type of documents in a mongodb collection:

- one where key sessions has a simple value:

  {"sessions": NumberLong("10000000000001")}
- one where key sessions has an array of values.

  {"sessions": [NumberLong("10000000000001")]}

Is there any way to retrieve all documents from the second category, ie. only documents whose value is an arary and not a simple value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of query for that:

```
db.collectionName.find( { $where : "Array.isArray(this.sessions)" } );
```

but you'd better convert all the records to one type to keep the things consistent.

Comment: @AlexeiKosov I agree that things should be consistent. This state was the result of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This code can be simple like this:

```
db.c.find({sessions:{$gte:[]}});
```

**Explanation:**

- Because you only want to retrieve documents whose **sessions** data type is array, and by the feature of **$gte** (if data types are different between tow operands, it returns false; Double, Integer32, Integer64 are considered as same data type.), giving an empty array as the opposite operand will help to retrieve all results by required.
- Also , `$gt, $lt, $lte` for standard query (attention: different behaviors to operaors with same name in expression of aggregation pipeline) have the same feature. I proved this by practice on MongoDB V2.4.8, V2.6.4.

Comment: You should add some details explaining why this is the solution to the question.

Comment: @Exa, you are right. I have appended the explanation in the result.